# Jquery checking form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I am trying to check certain fields in this form and if they aren't correctly filled that it cannot submit. My problem is that when I submit with some fields not filled in it does give the error but it still goes to mail and if I then fill my form in correctly the error doesn't disappear and it doesn't focus like I ask.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                   var naam = $("#naam").val();
                   var voornaam = $("#voornaam").val();
                   var bericht = $("#bericht").val();
                   if (naam == "" || voornaam == "" || bericht == ""){
                       $(".error").show();
                       if(naam == ""){
                           $("#naam").focus();
                       }
                       else if (voornaam == ""){
                           $("#voornaam").focus();
                       }
                       else{
                           $("#bericht").focus();
                       }
                   }
                   else{
                      $(".error").hide();
                      $("form").submit();
                       
                   }
                });
            });
        </script>
<form action="mailto:#" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
.error {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Try add `event.preventDefault();` inside `$("#submit").click(function(event){`. Or set the submit button to type button

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are not preventing the actual submit of the form.

You can use `event.preventDefault();`

In the example below, you can see if I have added `event.preventDefault();` inside the if statement where it fails. This will do so the form can't be submitted if the "validation" fails.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(event) {
    var naam = $("#naam").val();
    var voornaam = $("#voornaam").val();
    var bericht = $("#bericht").val();
    if (naam == "" || voornaam == "" || bericht == "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".error").show();
      if (naam == "") {
        $("#naam").focus();
      } else if (voornaam == "") {
        $("#voornaam").focus();
      } else {
        $("#bericht").focus();
      }
    } else {
      $(".error").hide();
      $("form").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="mailto:nielsvervoort14@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <input id="naam" />
  <input id="voornaam" />
  <input id="bericht" />
  <button  id="submit">submit</button>
  <div class="error">error</div>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't submit anymore when one of those fields isn't filled in that's great but It won't submit and it doesn't hide the error so I think I can't get to the final else statement any idea what the problem is there?

Comment: @NielsVervoort I can't tell you why it does not work for you, but as you can see in my example it does work just fine. Try look at your console log

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error, the if statement needs to prevent the default behaviour. Pass the event object into the function and call its preventDefault.

```
  $("#submit").click(function(e){
```

```
$(".error").show();
e.preventDefault();
```

You might also try approaching the problem differently; using the `<input type="text" required="required">` see https://devdocs.io/html/attributes/required

Comment: It doesn't submit anymore when one of those fields isn't filled in that's great but It won't submit and it doesn't hide the error so I think I can't get to the final else statement any idea what the problem is there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event preventDefault method. just like that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    // or return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `e.preventDefault()` only when there is an error that should prevent the form from submitting.

Also, the better way to check for empty fields is to check for the presence of only whitespace, not just comparing against an empty string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
       const re = /^\s*$/
       var naam = $("#naam").val();
       var voornaam = $("#voornaam").val();
       var bericht = $("#bericht").val();
       if (re.test(naam) || re.test(voornaam) || re.test(bericht)){
           e.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting
           $(".error").show();
           if(re.test(naam)){
               $("#naam").focus();
           }
           else if (re.test(voornaam)){
               $("#voornaam").focus();
           }
           else{
               $("#bericht").focus();
           }
       }
       else{
          $(".error").hide();
          $("form").submit();

       }
    });
});
```

This will indicate an error when the user not just leaves a field blank, but also fills in only spaces.